# Ubuntu downloads very slow. I don't find solution. help me please.

Tags: 13.04

I have a problem with Ubuntu 13.04, when I want to download something in direct download, I haven't tried torrent but I don't want such solution, is there a way to download the files faster without using any software for that task? I mean: setting up something in the software. All I find are programs. I have already changed the DNS using NAMEBENCH, but still I download slow. Thank you

Comment: I would change the internet provider if I would have problems with the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it'll solve your problem or not but you can try this downloader (which is actually a firefox addon): https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall . After you install this go to tools>DownloadThemAll! Tools>Manager (in firefox only).